# Nested JSON parsing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I am stuck in understanding this json. Can anyone help me in parsing. I need the value of key "ItemNo".

I could only do:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *arr = [[[json objectForKey:@"ShoppingBagRefList"] objectForKey:@"ShoppingBagRef"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if you want to access the single string use the following**

```
NSString *ItemNo = json[@"ShoppingBagRefList"][@"ShoppingBagRef"][0][@"BagDetail"][@"ShoppingBag"][@"ShoppingBagSectionList"][@"ShoppingBagSection"][0][@"ShoppingBagItemList"][@"ShoppingBagItem"][0][@"ItemNo"];

NSLog(@"ItemNo == %@",ItemNo);
```

or alternateway

**if you want to access the all string based on ItemNO then use the following**

```
 NSArray *ItemNo = json[@"ShoppingBagRefList"][@"ShoppingBagRef"][0][@"BagDetail"][@"ShoppingBag"][@"ShoppingBagSectionList"][@"ShoppingBagSection"][0][@"ShoppingBagItemList"][@"ShoppingBagItem"];

for (NSDictionary *temp in ItemNo) {

    NSString *getItemNo = temp[@"ItemNo"];
     NSLog(@"ItemNo == %@",getItemNo);
}
```

Comment: To get array need to remove last `[0]` So i have edited for that

Comment: Thank you so much @Anbu.Karthik. Can you please remove the structure screenshot from the answer :)

Comment: @Assassin - ya sure